# Android 5 Titanium webview rendering issue

Tags: android, webview, titanium-mobile

In my app using Ti 3.5.1, a simple webview isn't correctly displayed on Android 5. My code is

```
Ti.UI.createWebView({
   html: productHtml,
   enableZoomControls: false,
   scalesPageToFit: true,
   autoLink: Ti.UI.AUTOLINK_NONE
});
```

Webview ignores viewport meta tag and text appears too small.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was having a similar problem and setting borderRadius to 0 for the WebView fixed it for me. Also separately from that using the 21 platform API solved the problem.